# Email notification when friend request is sent and accepted in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I implemented the has_friendship gem in my rails app for friendship requests. I now want email notifications when a friend request is sent and when it's accepted (for example user A sends request to B, B gets notified. User B accepts the request and A gets notified. these are the controller actions I have for sending and accepting friend requests:

```
  def add_friend
    if current_user.friend_request(@friend)
      redirect_to my_friends_path, notice: "Friend request successfully sent."
    else
      redirect_to my_friends_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error sending the friend request"
    end
  end

  def accept_friend
    if current_user.accept_request(@friend)
      redirect_to my_friends_path, notice: "Friend request successfully accepted."
    else
      redirect_to my_friends_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error accepting the friend request."
    end
  end
```

I played around with the actionmailer but couldn't get it to work. 
Here's what I have so far for the mailer methods:

```
class FriendshipNotifier < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => 'do-not-reply@example.com'

  def sent_friend_requests(@friend)
    @friend = friend
    mail( :to => @friend.email,
          :subject => 'You have received a friend request.' )
     end
  end

  def accepted_friend_requests(@friend)
    @friend = friend
    mail( :to => @friend.email,
          :subject => 'Your friend request has been accepted.' )
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using Sendgrid. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the actionmailer code you attempted.

Comment: `couldn't get it to work.` is very vague. Can you please tell us what you observed and what you expected to observe? Have you checked that you have mail settings in your config/environment files? Are you new to Action Mailer? if so have you read the Rails guide on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really see anything of note in the terminal. I was expecting to see the results of the email. I do have the sendgrid set up in config/environment as I'm using that to send email confirmations when users sign up. I did look at the rails guide for this but i'm still having trouble adapting my code to what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Change `sent_friend_requests(@friend)` to `sent_friend_requests(friend)`  and also `accepted_friend_requests(@friend)`. If it is typo in the SO question ignore it else change it and give it a try.

Comment: where are you calling your mailer methods? this question isn't a reproducible example yet

Comment: Did you try adding FriendShipnotifier's methods straight into the code so that it knows to run? Add:
FriendshipNotifier.sent_friend_requests(@friend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the mailer methods to your methods should work

```
def add_friend
  if current_user.friend_request(@friend)
    FriendshipNotifier.send_friend_requests(@friend)
    redirect_to my_friends_path, notice: "Friend request successfully sent."
  else
    redirect_to my_friends_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error sending the friend request"
  end
end

def accept_friend
  if current_user.accept_request(@friend)
    FriendshipNotifier.accepted_friend_requests(@friend)
    redirect_to my_friends_path, notice: "Friend request successfully accepted."
  else
    redirect_to my_friends_path, flash[:error] = "There was an error accepting the friend request."
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that and it works in my terminal. I can see the email in my logs but for some reason the emails don't get sent in production (I'm using Heroku). Any ideas why? @user3693398

Comment: Nevermind, It works just fine, It just takes a while for the emails to come. Big thanks to everyone who took the time to look at it :-)